# why $\frac {z^n}{w^{n+1}}=\frac {z^n}{(w-z)w^n} ?$

Tags: complex-analysis

some  confusion in taylor theorem

my doubt is mark in red line  and given below in the photo

[image]

Im not getting  $$\frac{1}{w-z} = \frac{1}{w} + \frac{z}{w^2} +........+ \frac{z^{n-1}}{w^n}  + \frac {z^n}{(w-z)w^n}$$

My thinking is that  $$\frac{1}{w-z} = \frac{1}{w} + \frac{z}{w^2} +........+ \frac{z^{n-1}}{w^n}  + \frac {z^n}{w^{n+1}}$$

why $$\frac {z^n}{w^{n+1}}=\frac {z^n}{(w-z)w^n} ?$$

Comment: $1/(w-z)$ **isn't** $1/w+\cdots z^n/w^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that
$$\frac{z^k}{(w-z)w^k}-\frac{z^{k+1}}{(w-z)w^{k+1}}=\frac{z^k(w-z)}{(w-z)w^{k+1}}
=\frac{z^k}{w^{k+1}}.$$
Therefore
\begin{align}
&\frac1w+\frac z{w^2}+\cdots+\frac{z^{n-1}}{w^n}\\
&=
\left(\frac1{w-z}-\frac{z}{(w-z)w}\right)
+\left(\frac{z}{(w-z)w}-\frac{z^2}{(w-z)w^2}\right)
+\cdots+\left(\frac{z^{n-1}}{(w-z)w^{n-1}}-\frac{z^n}{(w-z)w^n}\right)
\\
&=\frac1{w-z}-\frac{z^n}{(w-z)w^n}
\end{align}
by telescoping.

Comment: thanks u @angina seng  i think u have  done typo mistake $\left(\frac1{z-w}-\frac{z}{(z-w)w}\right)$

I thinks it should be $\left(\frac1{w-z}-\frac{z}{(w-z)w}\right)$

Comment: @jasmine fixed, I hope!